# insert only if data not exists in DB

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I did some logic to insert non existent values of row into db but I failed. Here is partial code:

```
 $existTitleArr = array();


 $sql = "SELECT title FROM list";
 $result = $db - > query($sql);

 if ($result - > num_rows > 0) {

     while ($row = $result - > fetch_assoc()) {
         $existTitleArr[] = $row['title'];
     }
 }

 $counter = 0;

 foreach($dom as $data) {

     if ($counter < 10) {

         if (isset($data - > find('.cname a', 0) - > plaintext)) {
             $title = $data - > find('.cname a', 0) - > plaintext;
         }

         $title = trim($title);

         if ($title != $existTitleArr[$counter]) {

             $stmt = $db - > prepare("INSERT INTO list(title) VALUES (?)");

             $stmt - > bind_param('s', $title);

             $stmt - > execute();
         }

         $counter++;

     }
 }
```

Above code failed (I thought I did it) when I tried to delete one of the records and ran the script again. The rows inserted and became 19 instead of filling the  empty slots, I have no idea why.

I echo `$title` and `$existTitleArr[$counter]` and the value is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this issue only using an SQL query [INSERT INTO ... SELECT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp)

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO list (title) SELECT title FROM mainlist
```

However, for this query to work, you need to add a UNIQUE index on your title. I don't know if your title is unique or not.

If your title is not unique, I would suggest to add a FOREIGN KEY in `list` pointing to `mainlist`, then using the following query

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO list (id_mainlist, title) SELECT id, title FROM mainlist
```

Comment: so no need 2 query? combine them into 1?

Comment: my bad, mainlist is a typo, i only have one table.

Comment: @EltonJamie without mainlist, this answer is totally wrong. I don't quite understand what you are trying to do. When you say `insert non existent values of row into db`,  do you mean that you want a continuity with your table's id (1,2,3...10 instead of 1,4,5...13) even after deleting some lines ?